# Add a shadow to an UIView class with already existing override func layerClass

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview

Edit: Result of the code right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyNM4.jpg - what I want: https://uxplanet.org/neumorphism-in-user-interface-tutorial-c353698ac5c0

I am trying to create a custom UIView class to get an Neumorphism lookalike View:

```
import UIKit

class NeumorphicView: UIView {

    override public class var layerClass: Swift.AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Light shadow
        guard let shadowLayer = self.layer as? CAShapeLayer else {return}
        shadowLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.88, green:0.90, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        shadowLayer.cornerRadius = 15
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -3.0, height: -3.0)
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 3

    }
}
```

With this code, I already get a brighter pseudo border on the left and top. Now I want to add an darker shadow on the right and bottom.

I tried to copy the code above with different values, but obviously I had no success. How can I add a shadow border to my existing code?